# git: how to obtain the commit message of the file before it gets committed using pre-commit hook?

Tags: git, githooks

I am working on a hook script to get the commit message of the file that is currently being committed and to change the commit message and then commit, if it does not satisfy a pattern.

My question is, Is  there a way to get the commit message of the file before it is committed and change the commit message and then commit the file?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the commit-msg hook. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks. The commit message doesn't even exist when the pre-commit hook runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pre-commit` hook is intended to check the commited content and not the commit message.

You are probably looking for a `prepare-commit-msg` hook or more likely a `commit-msg` hook to make your change to the commit message.

Here is the ordered list of hooks related to the commit action:

- pre-commit: check commited changes ;
- prepare-commit-msg: prepare the commit message that can be edited by the user ;
- commit-msg: check or change the commit message after it has been saved by the user ;
- post-commit: can be used to send a commit notification.

See the [githooks man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) for more information about the different hooks.

Comment: Totally failed to notice that.. THANK YOU